# Finding correct SPAN tag using jQuery prev() and next()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey all I am needing the following html code to get the value of **"deliver best smile"** which seems to be **6 prev()** and **2 Next()**.

```
<div id="eea305a4-32b2-434d-8623-4dc3e2fcf119F_SelectMany" class="lfFormField
     lfFormFieldSelectMany  F_Form1-P_NewPage-F_SelectMany">
  <div class="">
    <fieldset class="composite-field-fieldset">
      <legend class="no-form-field-mandatory-sign-css">
        <span id="F_SelectMany-required"
              class="form-field-mandatory-sign-css lfFormFieldRequiredMarker no-form-field-mandatory-sign-css">*</span>
        <span class="form-field-title-sign-css lfFormLabel">deliver best smile</span>
      </legend>
      <div style="padding=left:0.1em" 
           dojoattachevent="onmouseover:onMouseOver, onclick:onClick, onmouseout:onMouseOut" 
           class="dojoDndHandle freedom-base-mixin-css" 
           id="eea305a4-32b2-434d-8623-4dc3e2fcf119F_SelectMany-widget" 
           widgetid="eea305a4-32b2-434d-8623-4dc3e2fcf119F_SelectMany-widget">
        <ul id="e2b7488e-a88c-4da0-8287-4f8e4e6091f4tbl" 
            dojoattachpoint="containerNode,focusNode" 
            class="selection-group">
          <li dojoattachpoint="listItem" 
              class="vertical-selection-group-item" 
              id="freedom_widget_solution_form_FreedomOptionButton_0" 
              value="0" type="checkbox"
              widgetid="freedom_widget_solution_form_FreedomOptionButton_0">
            <div class="selection-group-item-container notDojoDndHandle">
              <span dojoattachevent="onmouseover:onMouseOver, onclick:onClick, onmouseout:onMouseOut" 
                    class="selection-group-item-input dijitInline freedom-base-mixin-css freedom-base-mixin-cssChecked dijitChecked" 
                    widgetid="2ff949f4-c88e-4769-8e36-23c81661af92-btn">
                <input dojoattachpoint="textbox,focusNode,_aroundNode" 
                       id="2ff949f4-c88e-4769-8e36-23c81661af92-btn" 
                       class="dijitReset dijitCheckBox notDojoDndHandle" 
                       type="checkbox" tabindex="0" 
                       dojoattachevent="onclick:_onClick" 
                       role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" 
                       name="group_eea305a4-32b2-434d-8623-4dc3e2fcf119F_SelectMany-widget" 
                       value="Achieve and maintain quality" 
                       style="-webkit-user-select: none;">    
              </span>
              <div class="selection-group-item-text-container dijitInline">
                <label dojoattachpoint="titleNode" 
                       for="2ff949f4-c88e-4769-8e36-23c81661af92-btn" 
                       class="selection-group-item-text bold-selection-group-item">Achieve and maintain quality</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
```

My position at that time is at the **Achieve and maintain quality** value from the input tag.

Currently I tried the following:

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
   var testing = $(this).prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().next().next().html();
   console.log(testing);
   loop++;
}
```

The **var testing** is what I am trying to get that value from but it comes up with "undefined" so I am guessing I am not stopping at the correct spot?

Any help would be great!

Comment: Why not just Select its class? `.form-field-title-sign-css` .. it also seems to be unique within this markup sample.

Comment: The `<input />` tag is wrapped in a `<span>` and has no sibling nodes. Per the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/prev/), the `.prev()` function traverses siblings but does not traverse up the DOM tree so I don't think the `.prev()` solution you've outlined will work which is probably why you're getting undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try traversing up to the parent container and then doing a find on that element by it's class.

**For example:**

Traverse to parent by id:

```
$(this).closest('#eea305a4-32b2-434d-8623-4dc3e2fcf119F_SelectMany').find('.form-field-title-sign-css');
```

Traverse to parent by class:

```
$(this).closest('.lfFormField').find('.form-field-title-sign-css');
```

Or travers to parent by HTML element:

```
$(this).closest('fieldset').find('.form-field-title-sign-css');
```

And to get the value, in this case you would probably want to do `.text()` instead of `.html()`. Unless of course you actually want all the HTML.

And finally, if this id `F_SelectMany-required` isn't random. You could do this instead. Which should help it be a bit more specific.

```
$(this).closest('.lfFormField').find('#F_SelectMany-required').children('.form-field-title-sign-css');
```

Comment: @Ted, yes. I will add that one too

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck This first example would not work. Those letters/numbers are all random when the page reloads. Classes however stay the same name so I will give the second example a try.

Comment: @StealthRT, Okay I wasn't sure about that one. But figured I would throw it in there just in case. Although selecting by an ID would be best if possible. That way you can ensure it is unique and you are only going to get that one specific container. But I guess it all depends on your application.

Comment: also ID's should be unique, so `$("#my-id")` should always be the same result as `$(this).closest("#my-id")`, and possibly a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```js
$(function(){
    var $lbl=$("label[dojoattachpoint='titleNode']");    //Your position
    $lbl.click(function(){
        if (!$("#" + $(this).attr("for")).is(":checked")) {
            var $fieldset=$(this).closest("fieldset");
            alert($("legend",$fieldset).find("span").text());    
        }
    })    
})
```

Comment: Please don't use the "runnable code snippet" unless your code is runnable. Either use a standard code block or try adding jQuery and some sample html to show your code in action.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery's prev() gives you the previous **sibling**.  In the DOM of the document you are posting, the input with "Achieve and maintain quality" in the value, does not have any siblings.  It is the only child of the span that surrounds it, so you are going to get undefined no matter what combination of prev() and next() you do.  Did you mean to use parent() instead of prev()?
But much better to give that span an id
    
    deliver best smile
and get to it by using $("#SmileSpanId")